# Google Sheets to Google Calender

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to transfer information from google sheets to google calendar but the script I put in keeps saying:

> "Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.
> shopSchedule    @ Code.gs:31

I have very little experience with coding, and I am following the coding of another person, expect with my own variables, but I'm not sure what went wrong.

Here is overall script:

```
    function shopSchedule() {
  /**
      Task 1) Open The Event Calendar.
   */
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A52").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

/**
      Task 2) Pull the schedule information into the code, in a form that the code can understand.
 */
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:E2").getValues();

/**
      [
        [8/20/2021, Completion Date],
        [8,27,2021, Shipping Date]
      ]
 */

 /**
      Task 3) Do the work!
  */
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups[x];

    var jobName = shift[0];
    var jobDate = shift[1];

    eventCal.createEvent(jobName, jobDate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function shopSchedule() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ss.getRange("A52").getValue());
  const signups = ss.getRange("A1:E2").getValues();
  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    let shift = signups[x];
    let jobName = shift[0];
    let jobDate = new Date(shift[1]);//This will accept a lot of strings but if not you may need to extract the correct data from the string and use a date constructor
    let endDate = new Date(jobDate.getFullYear(),jobDate().getMonth(),jobDate.getDate(),jobDate.getHours() + 1);
    cal.createEvent(jobName, jobDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

[Date() Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Note: the monthIndex is a number from 0 to 11 not 1 to 12

Comment: Okay, I tried that but I changed a couple things: I took out line 9, and changed line 10 to : CalendarApp.createAllDayEvent(jobName, jobDate,); It allows me to run it without any issues, but nothing shows up on the calendar. I'm assuming it just isn't selecting the correct calendar. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Did you make sure to use the correct variable name (`cal` rather than `eventCal`)?

Comment: Great! Has the problem now been resolved?

Comment: Perhaps if that was the only error then maybe so.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry got the question asker/answerer mixed up :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the line `eventCal.createEvent(jobName, jobDate)`, the last line of your code. But I think you're actually trying to make an all-day event, in which case you would want to use `eventCal.createAllDayEvent(jobName, jobDate)`. You can see documentation for that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-date). (`createEvent` would require additional parameters, specifically both a start and end time.)

Comment: Alright, I adjusted after reading over the link you gave, and now I'm not getting any errors, it says that the Execution started and that the execution completed, but nothing changes on the calendar. I can edit the above post with the new script, and see what you think?